# Solving the double integral $\iint2y dydz$

Tags: integration

I have to solve an integral, I know the final answer but I don't understand it so any help is appreciated

I made a part of the exercise (which I don't think is important to show) and arrive at the integral:

$\iint2y dydz$

I know the limits for both y and z are 0 and 2

Here is the solution:

$\iint2y dydz= 2y^2|_0^2=8$

I don't get how you go from the first to second part

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to provide limits for $y $ **and** $z$.

Comment: What about $ z$'s limits? In a double integral, the domain of integration is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: For z the limits are 0 and 2 as well, I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the integrals from the inside out 
$$\int_0^2\left( \int_0^2 2y\ dy\right) \ dz=\int_0^2\left( y^2|_{y=0}^{y=2}\right)dz\\
=\int_0^24dz\\=8$$ 
They have reversed the order of integration, which is allowed by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)
$$\int_0^2\left( \int_0^2 2y\ dz\right) \ dy=\int_0^2\left( 2yz|_{z=0}^{z=2}\right)dy\\
=\int_0^24ydy\\=2y^2|_0^2\\=8$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ \mathcal{D}$ be defined as:

$$ \mathcal {D} := \left \{ (y.z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ 0 \leq y \leq 2, \ 0 \leq z \leq 2 \right \} $$

Then:

$$ \underset{\mathcal{D}}{\iint} 2 y \ \mathrm dy \ \mathrm dz = \int_{0}^2 \mathrm dz \int_{0}^2 2y \ \mathrm dy = \Big [z \Big]_{0}^2 \cdot \Big [ y^2 \Big ]_{0}^2 = 8  $$